# Post build task not working [Jenkins]

Tags: selenium, jenkins, automation, continuous-integration, jenkins-plugins

Can someone please help. I am trying to trigger a post-build action using the **post-build action** plugin. The log text that I inputted is returning false, hence not performing a post-build action. When I don't enter any text, it returns true.

This is a simple freestyle project that should print test if it matches the text 
[Post build setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ees5i.jpg)

This is the console output returning false
[Console output returning false](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QdUZU.jpg)

This is the output with no text 
[Output with no text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XVzgs.jpg)

Any help will be appreciated. All I want to do is perform a post-build action depending on if my build fails or passes. Alternate solution is welcomed

Thanks

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The root cause is your job has no any log out in Job Build Stage, please see `Post build task` plugin's help, this plugin will search job build log to find the text you specified in plugin.

[image]

A quick way to re-try is add a Build Step to print out something: 
1. `Execture shell` (if job executed on Linux machine) 
2. `Execute windows batch` (if job execute on Window machine)

A Job configure example:
[image]

Comment: I am running a maven project. Is there a way to get the console log output. Like using the cat logfile command, that way I can search for SUCCESS, FAILURE?